# How to debug c-mode-common-hook that doesn't fire

Tags: hooks, debugging, prelude

I'm using prelude mode, and in a file .emacs.d/personal/old-settings.el I have, amongst other things:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'comment-region)

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
      (lambda()
        (local-set-key  (kbd "C-c o") 'ff-find-other-file)))
```

Now when editing a c++-mode file, comment-region has been set, but ff-find-other-file hasn't.

I did F1 v c-mode-common-hook and see this:

```
c-mode-common-hook is a variable defined in `cc-vars.el'.
Its value is ((lambda nil
   (local-set-key
   (kbd "C-c o")
   'ff-find-other-file))
(lambda nil
  (run-hooks 'prelude-c-mode-common-hook)))
```

How would I go about debugging this? There doesn't seem to be a way to list-hooks, detect if the hook had already fired, etc.

Comment: `C-c C-c` is bound to `comment-region` in `c++-mode` by default (against my wishes).  BTW, `M-;` is the standard global binding to comment a region (using `comment-dwim` which provides a superset of the functionality of `comment-region`) and the use of `C-c C-c` for it is an old habit that's mildly discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could print a message from your hook, like this:

   (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
             (lambda()
               (message "fired")
               (local-set-key  (kbd "C-c o") 'ff-find-other-file)))
2. You can have a look at the current mode and his Key-Bindings with `C-h m`
3. You can write a short config.el which only handels the Part you try to debug and start it with `emacs -Q -l config.el`

Btw: I have done all 3 steps above and the hook fires.

*Can someone help me formating this code-snippet? :)*

Comment: Thanks, I think that has me going in the right direction. It seems that prelude mode has gone and defined a series of conflicting key-bindings, which I found via 2) above.


4 spaces at start of each line make the snippet appear as intended.

Comment: Glad I could help. Indenting did not work, because the code is in a list ... it seems

Comment: Thanks, I managed to identify that it was a conflicting keybinding doing this and I can now disable prelude mode by adding (prelude-off) to the hook as follows:

    (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda()
            (prelude-off)
            (local-set-key  (kbd "C-c o") 'ff-find-other-file)))